# How to restrict script scope from clearing whole column(s) to column(s) and row?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that is meant to clear certain columns upon changing contents of a cell. Can someone advise how I can prevent the script from clearing the entire column, but instead only clear the contents of the cells on the same row as the edited cell instead? Here is the current script, really appreciate any advise.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'clear contents of dependent cells
On Error Resume Next
If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Select Case Target.Column
    Case 2  'clear columns C and D and E
      Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), _
        Target.Offset(0, 3)).ClearContents
    Case 3  'clear column D and E
      Range(Target.Offset(0, 1), _
        Target.Offset(0, 2)).ClearContents
    Case 4 'clear column E

  End Select
End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Eg:  `Target.EntireRow.Cells(3).Resize(1,3).ClearContents` will clear C to E.

Comment: Instead of `On Error Resume Next` you should use `On Error GoTo exitHandler` otherwise this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: thanks for the advise! how can I restrict the entire script above to activate from row 12 downwards only - ie. I don't want to use the script at all on rows 1-12?